# Copy of Amazon EC2 LAMP AMI won't start

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two different AWS accounts. I copied an AMI from one account to another but when I try to start apache,

```
service httpd start
```

I get an error.

> Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs

I have a different elastic IP for the new account, could this be the problem? Where would I have to replace the IP address?

Comment: did you see if port `80` actually already in use? try `netstat --listen`

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because you are not a super user.

You can try this:
**sudo** service httpd start